# Data/YAML loop not looping in Jekyll

Tags: loops, jekyll, liquid

I have a page named `gallery.yml` in a folder called `/_data` in my Jekyll project, and I'd like to loop through the groups in `gallery.yml` and have the output in a new page in `/_includes`.

`gallery.yml`:

```
- name: Banana Shortcake
  color: yellow
  weight: 2 lbs

- name: Chocolate Mousse
  color: brown
  weight: 9 lbs
  rogue-item: Yum!

- name: Strawberry Fluff
  color: pink
  weight: 0.5 oz
```

The `.html` page in `/_includes`:

```
{% for gallery in site.data.gallery %}
<h1>{{ gallery.name }}</h1><!-- This should be Banana Shortcake -->
<p>The color of {{ gallery.name }} is {{ gallery.color }}, and its weight is {{ gallery.weight }}</p>

<h1>{{ gallery.name }}</h1><!-- This should be Chocolate Mousse -->
<p>The color of {{ gallery.name }} is {{ gallery.color }}, and its weight is {{ gallery.weight }}</p>
<p>Rating: {{ gallery.rogue-item }}</p>

<h1>{{ gallery.name }}</h1><!-- This should be Strawberry Fluff -->
<p>The color of {{ gallery.name }} is {{ gallery.color }}, and its weight is {{ gallery.weight }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But when I apply this, there is no loop - it just repeats the first grouping. Any hints as to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` tag is used to loop through the array and return for every item in the array.

```
{% for gallery in site.data.gallery %}
  <h1>{{ gallery.name }}</h1><!-- This should be Banana Shortcake -->
  <p>The color of {{ gallery.name }} is {{ gallery.color }}, and its weight is {{ gallery.weight }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

will automatically run 3 times to output the HTML as required.

Comment: I get it now! Thank you!